# Error When Using Move-PNPFolder on DocumentSet

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to use Move-PnPFolder to move a Document Set from one library to another library on the same site.

Code:

```
Move-PnPFolder -Folder $sourcePath -TargetFolder $destPath -Connection $devDestCon
```

Error:

```
Move-PnPFolder : This operation is not supported.
```

If this command is not available on Document Sets, what command should be used?

The source and destination libraries are identical.
List validations have been removed.
My test Document Set is empty / contains no files.
Classic Document Set experience*

SharePoint version:  SharePoint Online

Comment: Can you provide an example of your command? I have just tested it and I had no issues moving document sets with the Move-PnPFilder commandlet.

Answer (score 0):

> [Move a folder to another location in the current web](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps). If you want to
> move a folder to a different site collection, use the Move-PnPFile
> cmdlet instead, which also supports moving folders and also across
> site collections.

Here is a successful within the same site collection. Document sets A and B were moved from one library to another:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -UseWebLogin -Url https://tenant.Sharepoint.com/sites/Sandbox
Move-PnPFolder -Folder DocumentSetA/A -TargetFolder DocumentSetB
Move-PnPFolder -Folder DocumentSetA/B -TargetFolder DocumentSetB
```

[image]

If you are moving document sets across different subsites or site collections, then you should use the [Move-PnPFile commandlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
Move-PnPFile -SourceUrl "/sites/project/Shared Documents/Archive" -TargetUrl "/sites/archive/Project" -AllowSchemaMismatch -AllowSmallerVersionLimitOnDestination
```

Answer (score 0):

In my test, using the **Move-PnPFolder** command can successfully move the Document Set to another Document library in the same site.

**Here is the PnP PowerShell command:**

```
$SiteURL= "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
$username = "username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $username -Message "Type the password:"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credentials $credential
Move-PnPFolder -Folder 'Shared Documents/Set1' -TargetFolder 'Documents_B'
```

[image]

[image]

More information, please refer to **[this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/move-pnpfolder?view=sharepoint-ps)**.